# How to add soft edges on emerging animating object

Tags: modeling

I'm animating a simple cube shape, emerging from the floor. As it's revealing going in the Z axis, the edges of the cube look very sharp. Is there a way to make look more natural for the cube to have a feathering-Blurred edge effect to it?

Image A is from Blender, and Image B is from Photoshop for demonstration example:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You could give to your ground a *Volume* material, or a *Surface* material with some math for the transparency. Did you try one of those ?

Comment: Please elaborate more on this method you're suggesting, with some screenshots. This technique you're referring to, I haven't seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an *Input > Ambient Occlusion* node that you plug into a *Color Ramp*, if the *Only Local* option is disabled it will take into account the contact of your object with other objects. In Eevee don't forget to enable the *Ambient Occlusion* option in the *Render* panel:

[image]

Comment: Thank you kindly for the explanation and image example.